# tkinter checkboxes not working on canvas while entry field is

Tags: python, tkinter

I have checkboxes, button, and an entry field in a frame on a canvas, and a scrollbar that scrolls down the canvas. The following is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def add_skill():
    # creates a frame on a canvas and adds a scrollbar to the canvas.
    root = Tk()
    vscrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
    c = Canvas(root,yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
    vscrollbar.config(command=c.yview)
    vscrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
    f=Frame(c)
    c.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    c.create_window(0,0,window=f, anchor='nw')
    job_dictionary = {}
    with open("sample.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            job_dictionary[line.replace("\n","")] = IntVar()
    # row_ and column_ are used to determine the grid placement of all the checkbuttons.
    row_ = 2
    column_ = 0
    for line in sorted(job_dictionary.keys()):
        Checkbutton(f, text=line.replace("\"",""), variable=job_dictionary[line]).grid(row=row_, column=column_, sticky=W)
        row_ += 1
        if row_ > 100:
            row_ = 2
            column_ += 1
    job_dictionary["Name"] = Entry(f)
    job_dictionary["Name"].grid(row=0, column=0)
    Button(f, text='Submit', command=lambda:[actually_add_skill(job_dictionary),root.destroy()]).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
    Button(f, text='Quit', command=lambda:[root.destroy()]).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)
    job_dictionary["Work Trait?"] = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(f, text="Work Trait", variable=job_dictionary["Work Trait?"]).grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W)
    root.update()
    c.config(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))

def actually_add_skill(a):
    for key,value in a.items():
        print(key+": "+str(value.get()))

add_skill()

mainloop()
```

[sample.txt can be downloaded here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/189aCpSveywJYw3MzvsDzEu-8W0DHj5Nw/view?usp=sharing)

When I run this, it prints out the result of the entry box, but the checkbuttons all return 0 even if I press them. I just can't figure it out.

I tried creating a minimal reproducible code, which is the following:

```
from tkinter import *

def get_result(a):
    for key,value in a.items():
        print(key+": "+str(value.get()))
job_dictionary = {}
root = Tk()
vscrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
c = Canvas(root,yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
vscrollbar.config(command=c.yview)
vscrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
f=Frame(c)
c.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
c.create_window(0,0,window=f, anchor='nw')
job_dictionary["var"] = IntVar()
Checkbutton(f, text="var on?", variable=job_dictionary["var"]).grid(row=0, column=0)
Button(f, text='Print var value', command=lambda:[get_result(job_dictionary)]).grid(row=1, column=0)
job_dictionary["Work Trait?"] = IntVar()
Checkbutton(f, text="Work Trait", variable=job_dictionary["Work Trait?"]).grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=W)
root.update()
c.config(scrollregion=c.bbox("all"))
mainloop()
```

However that code works. Which is what confuses me. The only difference I can see between the two is that I use row_ and column_ to place the checkbuttons, but that shouldn't stop it from working.

Comment: The code works fine for me.  Did you have another instance of `Tk()` elsewhere in your original code?

Comment: yeah I do but I only every have one window at a time (each window destroys itself and then calls another window). The commenter below has informed me of toplevel so I'm going to implement that soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are calling `mainloop()` instead of `root.mainloop()`. I rewrote your entire program, right quick. No offense, but your way was clustered and confusing. Build off of this.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

#for storing top bar controls
control = tk.Frame(root)
control.pack(side='top', fill='x')

#create scrollable frame
scroll_frame = tk.Canvas(root)
scroll_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

main = tk.Frame(scroll_frame)
scroll_frame.create_window(0,0, window=main, anchor='nw')

vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root)
vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')

vsb.configure(command=scroll_frame.yview)
scroll_frame.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)


#selected skills printer
skills = {}
def print_skills():
    for k, v in skills.items():
        print(f'{k}: {v.get()}')
        

#create skill table                
i = 0
with open("sample.txt", "r") as file: 
    for line in sorted(file):
        key = line.replace("\"","").strip()
        skills[key] = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Checkbutton(main, text=key, variable=skills[key]).grid(row=(i%100), column=(i//100), sticky='w')
        i += 1


#update dimensions   
root.update()
scroll_frame.config(scrollregion=scroll_frame.bbox("all"))


#control bar elements
name_ent = tk.Entry(control)
name_ent.grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(control, text='Submit', command=print_skills).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')
tk.Button(control, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='w')
trait_iv = tk.IntVar()
tk.Checkbutton(control, text="Work Trait", variable=trait_iv).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='w')


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the response! A couple questions: 

1. Is the only thing you added root.mainloop()? 

2. The full code creates new windows when the user clicks on certain buttons. At the end of the code I have just mainloop(). Should I instead write [window name].mainloop() at the end of each function? 

Also a comment, the reason I wrote the gui for the window in the function is because I need to create new different windows later and I haven't learned classes yet, which I believe are useful for tkinter windows.

Comment: @Friend_Slayer666 ~ see the edit at the bottom of my answer. I rewrote your entire code. It should answer all of your questions. You should only ever have 1 `mainloop` and 1 `root`. Use `tk.Toplevel` to create more windows.

Comment: thank you very much! It'll take some work but I'm going to rewrite it using Toplevel.

Last question: why do you use tk.Toplevel rather than just Toplevel?

Comment: @Friend_Slayer666 ~ `from tkinter import *` pollutes your namespace. It is better to use an alias, such as `import tkinter as tk`. Then everything becomes `tk.Button`, `tk.Entry`, etc.... I made one change to my answer. `control` has been moved out of `main` to the `root` so it will not scroll with your table and no regard needs to be made for it's row in generating skills. Please consider selecting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Friend_Slayer666 ~ Sure. Go to youtube and watch one of those 3 hour long videos that try to sum up the entire language. Use SO search, read questions and answers, and understand them. Take simple tutorials. Read the docs. Find basic SO questions and do "speed-research" to answer them. The grand majority of answers to questions (asked and to-be-asked) already exist in one form or another, all over the internet

Comment: thanks. I already know the very basics but it's clear from the questions that I see here that I don't know as much as I thought I did. I'll look into watching some youtube videos.

Comment: @Friend_Slayer666 ~ "I already know the very basics" - Nope. You may be aware of a bit of the basics, but you definitely do not know the very basics. I say this because, you didn't even know how your import signatures affect your code, and you'll use something like `replace('\n', '')` instead of `strip()` for line pruning. It's OK, though. You have a desire to learn and advance so, of course you will! I have 25 years programming in numerous languages, and I discover new things almost every day.

Comment: @Friend_Slayer666 - I can give you one more piece of advice. If you have an idea ... try it! A perfect example is: when I was cleaning up your skill generation loop, I knew I could compress your logic if I could sort the file (instead of the dict). When I wrote `sorted(file)` my thought was "Will this actually work?". It did, and you can reverse segue that back to me learning something new almost every day. If it wouldn't have worked, I probably would have sat there and thought about it until I could make it work another way, efficiently.

Comment: yeah I noticed that, it was clever. Thanks for the advice